# How to make USB NIC adapter persistent on boot with Centos 6x

Tags: centos, usb

I am adding a USB ethernet adapter to box running centos 6x. If I add the USB device after boot, the system enables it and it works. However, after reboot, the device is no longer accessible unless I pull out the USB device an re-insert it. There are entries in udev and ifcfg-ethX for the                                                         device.

This article refers to uevents.
https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-udev.html#sec-udev-kernel

Is there something I need to do that will allow this device to be accessible after reboot?